# Executing API Google Sheets in PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I have made a website that works with the API of Google Sheets. In local everything works without errors, but when I upload the files to my server I get an error message that says:

**"Warning: require_once(..\google-api-php-client-2.2.0\vendor\autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /(my_route)/app.php on line 3"**

and also **"Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '..\google-api-php-client-2.2.0\vendor\autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php-7.0/pear') in /my_route/app.php on line 3"**

In app.php is where I have the function of getClient() which I need in order to access to my file in Google Drive.

I am working with the Sheets API v4 and PHP 7.0

Also I have a free server in hostinger which also run PHP 7.0

If you need more info ask me anything. Thank you.

Update: 
If I add scandir() in google-api-php-client-2.2.0/vendor I get:
Warning: scandir(../google-api-php-client-2.2.0\vendor): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /my_route/app.php on line 2

Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory in /my_route/app.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

Typically the `vendor` folder is located inside the your project folder. Which means the autoload file is included in your app like this vendor/autoload.php.

Revisit your project directory structure and make the necessary adjustments. Move vendor file inside your project folder.

Comment: I have: /MAIN_FOLDER/PHP/my_file.php and also: MAIN_FOLDER/google-api-php-client-2.2.0/... so I need to write ../google-api-php-client-2.2.0/vendor/autoload.php